# Docker-compose + Dockerfile + Selenium Chrome Driver = unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, docker-compose, dockerfile

Good Morning Everyone!

***Current scenery***
I've createad an API that uses selenium(Chrome-driver) to get data from a specific website and save it into a database. I've been trying to create a Docker that make it for me. The selenium script is running perfectly outside of Docker.

***Dockerinzing***

Because I need to connect in a Mysql database (to get data to search in api) and connect to Postgresql (to insert data that I received from selenium), I created a docker-compose to connect to them.

This is my docker-compose configuration:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.3
    volumes: 
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes: 
      - /home/user/db/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /home/user/db/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passroot
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_HOST: host
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
  web:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
```

and to create Docker, I created the Dockerfile below:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

COPY pom.xml /usr/local/service/pom.xml
COPY src /usr/local/service/src

# Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget unzip curl dpkg

#Install Open JDK 8
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk

# Install Chrome for Selenium
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
RUN dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
RUN rm /chrome.deb

# Install chromedriver for Selenium
RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Setup JAVA_HOME, this is useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Install Maven 
RUN java -version && ls -l /usr/bin/java    
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install maven -y
RUN java -version && ls -l /usr/bin/java  

WORKDIR .
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
COPY src /tmp/src/
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN mvn package

WORKDIR .

RUN cp -a target/*.jar /app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The docker-compose is build and run normally, but when I do a request in my api, I received the following message error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-24T12:36:19.023+0000",
    "status": "500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "mensagem": "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.4.0-131-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 1.47 seconds\nBuild info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'\nSystem info: host: '41cd92b21873', ip: '172.18.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-131-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_191'\nDriver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver"
}
```

I tried many others Chrome's and Chrome-driver's versions, but it's not work.

I've searched in many others forums and they suggested me the following configuration(I had already used chrome headless configuration):

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

But it's not working for me!

Someone can help me to solve this or suggest me to do something better?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm curious, was the duplicate issue actually the problem?  I'm running into the same thing but I'm already setting in a way.